# Async google e-commerce analytics code not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

I've following code on my final checkout page to track e-commerce transactions. However, after having several transactions, I don't see any transaction in the analytics account. 
I have enabled ecommerce option in my analytics account. Can someone please point if there
are any issue in the following code or suggest tools for debugging this.

This is inside body tag

```
<body>
   ...
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxx']);
   _gaq.push(["_setDomainName", ".abc.com"]);
   _gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker", true]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

   _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
            '456',            // order ID - required
            'EcoStrip',  // affiliation or store name
            '34.95',           // total - required
            '0.0',           // shipping
            'Santa Clara',        // city
            'California',
            'USA'
          ]);

          _gaq.push(['_addItem',
            '456',  // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction
            '67333',           // SKU/code - required
            'USB EcoStrip 2.0 Energy Saving Power Strip',        // product name
            'Office',   // category or variation
            '34.95',          // unit price - required
        '1'
          ]);
    //Now submit the transaction
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics server

   (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
                          'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();
</script> 

  </body>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you ever resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason: Your `addTrans` call is missing a parameter between the total parameter and the shipping parameter: The tax parameter. If you don't charge tax, you can just hardcode this value to '0'.

```
   _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
            '456',            // order ID - required
            'EcoStrip',  // affiliation or store name
            '34.95',           // total - required
            '0', // tax
            '0.0',           // shipping
            'Santa Clara',        // city
            'California',
            'USA'
          ]);
```

Without a tax parameter, all of the parameters after total are off by one. So, the tax is set to 0, shippping is set to 'Santa Clara', city is set to 'California', and state/region is set to USA', and country gets set to 'undefined'.

See [Google Analytics Help Center article](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addTrans) for details.

Now, even if you fix this, it's not guaranteed to be the source of your problems. But it's a start.

As far is debugging this, Google Analytics released a very helpful Chrome Extension for debugging Google Analytics, called the [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code, lets see if it works. Does it matter to place this code in <body> tag versus <head> tag. I'll wait for few hours to see if it gets reflected.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where its placed, as long as your ecommerce data populates.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a bespoke multi domain e-commerce platform (2 years in the making), the backend is all in T-SQL/MSSQL 2008 and the front end runs on PHP 5.3 Apache and has recently been ported from C# on IIS7. Since moving to PHP the tracking only works some times.

There must be some difference in the way IIS serves pages compared to PHP, and this is causing tracking to not work. Or maybe Google doesn't want it to work every time, to save on server hits.

I have used the GA debug tool, followed Google's instructions to the letter and still the beacon only sends on first hit to the site, or if I click the Chrome page refresh button.

Anyone had a similar problem? The code is 100% correct I've even tried removing all other JavaScript from the page and I always clear the browser cache when testing.

If anyone can tell me why this happens great, but in the meantime I have a work a round that other people may find useful. It will force their tracking to track every time.

In short the fix is to make the browser parse (if that's the right term) all the javascript in the page fully everytime. There are many ways to do this, my approach is to create a PHP file that is non cache-able and has a small varying file size. Maybe this is overkill - I don't know, but it works. The php file should be called anything.php and contain the following code only.

```
(function GA_FIX(){
  var gafix = '<?php echo md5(rand(1,20));?>';
})
```

You might want add php headers to set the mime type to text/javascript, and cache expires headers depending on your Apache config. E.G if you have caching enabled for .js files.

Now link to that file from your site immediately before the GA tracking code like this. You tracking code should be just before the closing head tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/path_to_php_file.php"></script>
    <!-- google tracking code here-->
```

Your GA tracking will now work 100% of the time. This IS tried and tested and in production while I wait for an official answer telling me (and the rest of you) how to get it working.